# How to get NavMeshAgent Horizontal and Vertical Inputs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, navmesh

I have a 2D freeform directional blend tree, have horizontal and Vertical float values inserted. I just want them to be updated automatically when my character moves, I'm not moving the character using keyboard or Mouse I'm merely setting Destination for the character to go to

[image: Blend Tree]

[image: Blend Tree horizontal and Vertical values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save last position and check direction every frame.
For example:

```
public class AnimationDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 _lastPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _lastPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var currentPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
        var moveDirection = currentPosition - _lastPosition;
        CalculateAnimation(moveDirection);
        _lastPosition = currentPosition;
    }

    private void CalculateAnimation(Vector3 moveDirection)
    {
        //you have moveDirection to send in your animation system
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the moving direction. Combine that with the look-direction (`transform.forward`). Use [Vector3.Dot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html) to calculate the sideways movement factor. And maybe [SignedAngle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SignedAngle.html) to get the sideways direction (left or right).
Then, play with the NavMeshAgent's turn speed.